# How to access host ip address using host pc name in wifi network using android

Tags: java, android

In Java I have used following code to get ip using hostname

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("hp-PC");
System.out.println(address.getHostAddress());
```

when I am trying to used this code in android then it display

> Host Not Found

error, please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For me it works only when I add **.local** in the host name while getting the IP address of the machine in the local network.

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("hp-PC.local");
System.out.println(address.getHostAddress());
```

Not sure if this works out for you or not.

Comment: not working this answer please help in detail erro unownHostException